# Javascript | For loop - What is my syntax error?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, syntax, for-loop

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
    var gallerynr = 3;
    var thumbsnrA = new Array(gallerynr);

    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;
    var d = 0;

    for (d = 0; d == gallerynr; d++) {
        thumbsnrA[a] = 22;
        a ++;
        b ++;
    };

    alert(thumbsnrA);
```

**Result (should be):**

> 22,22,22

**But my Result is:**

> ,,

What is wrong with the syntax of my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You test is wrong.

```
for (d = 0; d < gallerynr; d++) {
```

is what you want

If you have

```
for (d = 0; d == gallerynr; d++) {
```

it only runs when d is 3 and it is not 3 from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Your array variable is declared as `thumbsnr`, but you reference `thumbsnrA` later on in the code.

Edit - OK, so you've changed your code! There is a misplaced semi-colon after your loop - that could be throwing the error.

Comment: yeah I saw that typo here after posting it - im sorry

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a delimiter after the closing brace of the for loop, and if d!=gallerynr before the loop, then the for loop will never be entered.